# Why my fields are not getting added to the database?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I am trying to add some fields to the column of my table. When I check my table, I see that the column could be created but the fields could not be added. However, I get no error or anything.

```
public function isset_row($target, $sender_table, $receiver_table, $sender_row) {
    $this->load->model('Connection_model');
    if ($this->Connection_model->get_custom_db($target)->get($sender_table)) {

        // Add column(s)
        $this->myforge = $this->load->dbforge($this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('receiver'), TRUE);
        $fields = array(
                $sender_row => array('type' => 'TEXT')
        );
        $this->myforge->add_column($receiver_table, $fields);

        $query = $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('sender')->get($sender_table);
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            echo $row->$sender_row . '<br>'; // Returns fields from a table (string)
            echo $receiver_table; // Returns table name (string)
            $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('receiver')->update($receiver_table, $row->$sender_row);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit1:

```
var_dump($this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('receiver')->update($receiver_table, $row->$sender_row));
```

This line returns *bool(false)*

Edit2:

With the update() function I am just saying to add the fields to the table but I am not saying to which column of the table. I think that must be the point but how can I specify the column when trying to update?

Comment: what do you mean adding field? Do you mean you insert(or update) some data into table?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Yes, exactly.

Comment: see doc https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: @RezaSaadati `if ($this->Connection_model->get_custom_db($target)->get($sender_table))` this condition doesn't make any sense..

Comment: @NarendraSisodia why not?  If it is true, then it means the table exists.

Comment: @RezaSaadati try to echo this condition

Answer (score 0):

Complete your model get_custom_db(). Use get() query builder method in model. So your condition should like this

```
if ($this->Connection_model->get_custom_db($table_name)) {
...
}
```

and use get() in model

```
public function get_custom_db($table_name){
  ....
  $test = $this-db->get($table_name);
  return $test->result();
}
```

OR provide the model code, I'll figure out it for you. Thanks